# How do I align content inside div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]

How do I align the content properly to fit inside the border box. If you see the image attached, the content has bit of space on left. I tried removing the `container` class, played around a lot with margin and padding but nothing has worked. It looks like I haven't applied css(bootstrap) in a proper way and also the nav-bar on zoom is not responsive.

I am not sure what is pushing the content to right. How do I fix this?

Created plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/iOMp9w4LjIknj11UkFwz?p=preview

Comment: are you looking for something like this - https://plnkr.co/edit/mPn0CiSJwhY1GdgCN2Gx?p=preview

Comment: Add a main wrapper and give that a margin 0 auto

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.container-fluid` instead of `.container`. Also use `.container-fluid` inside `.navbar-nav` and for this one consider removing its padding:

```
.navbar .container-fluid {
    padding: 0;
}
```

A complete example:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="title"><strong>Title</strong>
                <br/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li ui-sref-active="active" class="active"><a ui-sref="phone"><i class="fa fa-phone-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                <li style="border-right: #B2B9BA 1px solid;" ui-sref-active="active" class="active"><a ui-sref="message"><i class="fa fa-commenting-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li ui-sref-active="active" class="active"><a ui-sref="dialpad"><i class="fa fa-th-large" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                <li ui-sref-active="active" class="active"><a ui-sref="dialpad2"><i class="fa fa-stop" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

My [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/q0msk43YlRhCp8o4tENE?p=preview)

Comment: The button on footer is stlll having same issue

Comment: I have given `margin:2% 0% 0% -5.3%;` to footer button which fixed the white space inside div but it is not responsive on zoom

Answer (score 0):

in your code in header.html you added the class pull-right, just remove it, it has `float:right !important`

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
```